# Automatic disconnect telnet in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

When i run the script below, it connects the server but it disconnect before sending a command. How can i solve this problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect << EOD 
spawn telnet 31.168.109.31
sleep 2
expect ">"
sleep 1
send "my_password"
send  "\n"
sleep 1
interact
```

Comment: Before spawn  try to add timeout like `set timeout 200`

Comment: i try it.. but not change in result.. login that ip and disconnecting immediately..

Comment: Also remove `sleep` between `spawn` and `expect` and also remove sleep between `expect` and send password.

Comment: Also what you expect after sending password?

Comment: i remove that you say 'sleeps steps'.. but i dont see wanted result in console.. Also i expect ">" after sending password..

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you expect `>` before password. I am not getting you what is purpose of it  but as for some example script look here. It's might be not an answer but probably help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect << EOD 
set timeout 200
spawn telnet  31.168.109.31
expect "login:"
send "root\r"
expect "password"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "root#"
#rest of your logic what you want.
```

Comment: 'set timeout 200' why is there??

Comment: @user3523492 so telnet prompt will time out in 200 seconds if it not find any activity on it.

Comment: @user3523492 can't connect means? Are able to ping on lab IP?

Comment: 'telnet ip' comment is working/..  after the ' send "password" ' command , the password print to the screen ; after then disconnecting the ip ('telnet ip') .. Am i able to tell ?

Comment: @user3523492 yes.but Are you doing anything or expect anything after `send password`?